# Orckestra C1: Can a Date formatter be applied to a Tree Definition DataElement Label attribute?

Tags: c1-cms, orckestra-cms

I know for a Tree Definition of DataElementFolder, there is a DateFormat attribute, but the DataElement node doesn't have such an attribute.

```
<DataElements Type="MA.PressRelease.Article" Label="${C1:Data:MA.PressRelease.Article:Date}" Display="Auto">
```

This will show up looking like this.

[image]

It would be nice to have something like "Month day, Year" (Ex: May 4, 2017)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Orckestra/C1-CMS-Foundation/issues, open a new issue, starting with the Title "Feature Request:"  make a clear explanation about the benefits and anything else that you think that would improve and wait for response.

Comment: Thank you. Request opened. 
https://github.com/Orckestra/C1-CMS-Foundation/issues/442

Answer (score 0):

No, as of the latest release the date format is hard-coded:

https://github.com/Orckestra/C1-CMS-Foundation/blob/dev/Composite/C1Console/Trees/DataFieldValueHelper.cs#L65

Answer (score 0):

Per version 6.2 of C1 CMS you can control the label format for fields of type DateTime, decimal and int - thanks to [your feature request](https://github.com/Orckestra/C1-CMS-Foundation/issues/442).

Usage: Append a colon and then a format string to your label directive, for example:

```
<DataElements Type="MA.PressRelease.Article" Label="${C1:Data:MA.PressRelease.Article:Date:MMM d, yyyy}" Display="Auto">
```

The format string is the same you would use with .ToString() for the type of the field, ex "MMM d, yyyy" for dates, "F1" or "C" for decimals and ints.